# OBJECTPROPERTY(Owner_Id) Does Not Work For Triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I want to get the table name of a trigger. I use OBJECTPROPETY() founction with 'OwnerId' as property input.

```
Select ObjectProperty(Object_Id('TriggerName'), 'OwnerId')
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105(v=sql.110).aspx) it should return the parent_object_id. Bu it returns 1. What am I missing?

I use SQL Server 2012 btw.

[image: ObjectProperty]

Comment: You're reading the documentation wrong if you think that's what it says.

Comment: So, what should I understand from **child objects (those where parent_object_id is nonnull) will always return the same owner ID as the parent**

Comment: The parent of the trigger is the table. The owner_id for the table is 1. `owner_id != object_id`.

Comment: But I want the parent_id of trigger. Isn't this true: ' Trigger.parent_id = Table.object_id'

Answer (score 0):

The owner of a trigger is the Schema, not Table. The schema_id is 1 then the owner_id is 1.